# I want to see it closer or I want to see it closer up (or something else?)

Tags: word-choice

I am teaching direct object pronouns in French and preparing a cloze exercise where students will fill in gaps with the correct LE or LA pronoun. As a clue, I give them a translation of the part of the sentence containing the pronoun (with the noun it stands for between brackets). Below is my problem sentence:

'*Je suis trop loin de ce tableau, j’ai envie de* **LE** *voir de plus près*.'

Clue: [...] I would like to see **it** (the painting) closer.

or should it be

[...] I would like to see **it** (the painting) closer up.

or even

[...] I would like to see **it** (the painting) close up.

None of them feel right to me.... Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is

> I would like a closer view of **it** (the painting).

Comment: Ah, yes! That is perfect!  Thank you so much!